# List full commit history

Tags: git

I understand the syntax of `git log`. I'm trying to compile a list of all commits on the repository essentially with the sole purpose of showing the amount of work I must have put into the final code (sounds silly, I know, but I have a non-technical audience that already views version control as miraculous); eventually I plan to format this into a pretty LaTeX list. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd ever quantify "number of commits" as "amount of work".  Not unless you publicly claim to have rebased that repository (then again, if it's a non-technical audience, "rebase" would be lost on them...).

Comment: @Makoto I wouldn't either. But my audience would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current best way yo showcase your contribution is by using [**IonicaBizau/git-stats**](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats):

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/be233aefaee218732226d289a1dc1fd13764f342/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f4c664c4a4161452e706e67]

> examples:

```
git-stats # Displays your commit calendar
git-stats -v
git-stats -h
git-stats --light # Light mode
git-stats -s '1 January 2012' # All the commits from 1 January 2012, to now
git-stats -s '1 January 2012' -u '31 December 2012' # All the commits from 2012
```

Comment: Git Stats 2.0.0 is out! I updated the answer with the new options. :)